# Creating a custom jQuery selector using the Sizzle extension API

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sass, sizzle

I'm trying to figure out the Sizzle extension API. In particular, I'm trying to get jQuery to recognize the sass-style `&` selector (referring to the 'current element').

For example, I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
var current        = $('#current');
var sameAsCurrent  = current.find('&');
var childOfCurrent = current.find('& > div');
```

I've tried adding `&` as a [finder](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki--finding) and as a [filter](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-filtering). I've even tried monkey-patching the jQuery library. I've had no luck with any of these approaches so far. Shouldn't this be one of the easiest selectors to add?

Comment: `var childOfCurrent = current.find(' > div');`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Yes, I know. :-) But I'd like to get some consistency with SASS syntax, as well as learn about the Sizzle extension API.

Comment: @Joe: Unfortunately those references are all about custom *pseudo-selectors*, i.e., selectors starting with `:`. Indeed, that seems to be the only kind of help I could find with Google. But it's not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar with a custom `:this` pseudo selector. [Is it possible to create custom jQuery selectors that navigate ancestors? e.g. a :closest or :parents selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721390/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-jquery-selectors-that-navigate-ancestors-e-g-a/25733588#25733588)

I could not find a way to solve it using anything else available (not without replacing/hacking Sizzle completely), but it would probably work with `&` or `#current` with a simple change.

Based on my previous answer you could probably do this:

```
// Add findThis method to jQuery (with a custom :this check)
jQuery.fn.findThis = function (selector) {
    // If we have a :this selector
    if (selector.indexOf('&') || selector.indexOf('#current') > 0) {
        var ret = $();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var el = this[i];
            var id = el.id;
            // If not id already, put in a temp (unique) id
            el.id = 'id'+ new Date().getTime();
            var selector2 = selector.replace('&', '#' + el.id).replace('#current', '#' + el.id);
            ret = ret.add(jQuery(selector2, document));
            // restore any original id
            el.id = id;
        }
        ret.selector = selector;
        return ret;
    }
    // do a normal find instead
    return this.find(selector);
}
```

And use like this:

```
var current        = current.findThis('#current > s.someclass');
var sameAsCurrent  = current.findThis('&');           // kind of pointless, but works
var childOfCurrent = current.findThis('& > div');
```

The way it works is to add a temp selector to the "current" element, and replaces the chosen symbol (`#current` or `&`) with a selector for that temp id. It puts the original id back after the `findThis` call.